# transform.childCount not working as intended

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am building my first game with unity, a simple break out game.i am intending that when the level has no children it moves to the next level.but it doesn't seem to work.in the code I put this in the update methode.

```
else if (_currentLevel != null && _currentLevel.transform.childCount == 0)
                {
                    SwitchState(State.LEVELCOMPLETED);
                }
                break;
```

which call this code

```
case State.LEVELCOMPLETED:
                Destroy(_currentBall);
                Destroy(_currentLevel);
                Level++;
                PanelLevelCompleted.SetActive(true);
                SwitchState(State.LOADLEVEL, 1.0f);
                break;
```

but it doesn't even get into the first condition although in the editor i can see there's no  Childrens.
PS:Sorry if it's not clear if any more details are needed I will add them.

Comment: Are you sure that `_currentLevel` is not `null` ? Or that you reference the correct object?

Comment: Surely it has a camera. A light. A ball? Thats at least 2 or more?

Comment: I tried removing the '_currentLevel != null' and just try the second half it throws a NullReferenceException, is there another way to check if the level is Empty

Comment: @Racso .. what? ^^ The exact opposite .. OP is doing a null check so if it was `null` it will simply not reach the second check and not enter the `if` block .. if it was not `null` then why should it throw the exception since it is not `null` ? ;)

Comment: @hamzakesraoui well ... this simply means that your `_currentLevel` is (as I suspected) `null` meaning you didn't assign it .. now why this is the case is up to you to figure out .. we don't have your code/project in front of us

Comment: @BugFinder OP isn't asking if there are any objects in the Scene but any children nested under a certain given object ;)

Comment: @derHugo im sure thats what he meant. But its not actually what he said.

Comment: @BugFinder `i am intending that when the level has no children it moves to the next level` .. I'd say yes it is what they say, `level` != Scene

Answer (score 0):

I figure out what was wrong exactly, I failed to assigne the Instantiated level to the current level. I didn't add that part of code in the answer which made it very unclear.

In summary instead of

```
Instantiate(levels[Level]);
```

I added

```
_currentLevel = Instantiate(levels[Level]);
```

and it worked as intended.